Verify jwt token using only hashlib
I find pyJWT and other auth libraries are overly complex and, as a result, are often broken.  Not to mention providers tend to add their own special steps quite often.  As a result, I want to start dealing with JWT's without 3rd party libraries.
Here is a JWT I want to verify, using only crypto libraries. It comes from an AWS sandbox I set up and tore down, so there is no risk.
jwt = 'eyJraWQiOiJIVWliRnBkUjM2MW92QUxRVFdVeGx3V0pOUmc1SEVRQkxsUjEzTWIyejI0PSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.J_iS209k6Nsqmwf2XlK1kOeRCKjY-y6U28MicQTD8LFb3v-sC6sttYVya5kBb_qj3hnIDuXFvH3POlduBJhxiiXE7A3eAA9_09eYqmyna3tuNl_1W5pz_wlR9uhtOdhk0hAQWiaTaDViDjiEO6TPenEat0dz-yQWMp2Fda64yUOHFFiRZj5UsfO6_fUbOFlVzsmgwLhRPb5smIHkB4yFtcs4A1QI_fGyS9cEFTusKyt-JBmmdkfN83i8tiLfZV_IYUj0J5z-_vMSVOTg5yDMjcVCEswX1ZFUkm_FB2aLkAxPJxgzdDVAFSdg1UcITJjcfjFjPwi79quJEoEuYUahIQ'

jwk = {'keys': [{'alg': 'RS256',
   'e': 'AQAB',
   'kid': 'uNMjrozHoL/XMU+MGETT4ib+zErEVOpmI5TXcgP5TSQ=',
   'kty': 'RSA',
   'n': '_CkIlBfFJAtILPaVlQTNQySqSBWV63NXSgX0zcIIPf8o2HaweQZGG3kdETK8Vmcf_k_74sYpTuDOJ5x7UNNC24bJJhkoRcAkhSGNEUFQvEur0XCDzMjgFhWBsSS36Qs_wxGFZoeDHuEFyNmVGMlVg1drCxqCCrf-QV7rPKF-h7UIsrJxw_yf60y_Wh7iSiOgD7nc3lUBFh_2QJRAYv0AcaXpWwFVrT4IO4GrgU3s74kQn7I4R5q1L95CX1J3WA4MKaPObmBzWIo0Lg-uULAf3f-gEAMeZuwl4JLwhDHhoqqeiuz9g_ox5HaHwq5678xGtiz1K48WmvSzF_zY_P541w',
   'use': 'sig'},
  {'alg': 'RS256',
   'e': 'AQAB',
   'kid': 'HUibFpdR361ovALQTWUxlwWJNRg5HEQBLlR13Mb2z24=',
   'kty': 'RSA',
   'n': 'zC80KpQ--HfK2DHSydIXLWNcw0zGJjvzXygsuxG8tpaY2jgBjKN3iQjVYiBVwiOkYGza49hakU3C8WG8PPCCJrREOfw-IS9Zc0ZQmnuRtZTyvQhTYHy37IQpjQP9wWif74bWzTraPNy18PhtyEJcfW_LGa7s5p3vgYk3-ZXHk1AEyebZWIWFy1kjexMDiFwJJ69Ff6o8lx4LC_H17AGW-0S_IQrUxXExWBXc0zGV_QCBQbuv5frEg7tbHSYhkKLgVb0TZhACnGpfB7owiH2_4k5AHIgfvZxRXsBKGZEqBKJxV3dyszqGFeRQda65-J8dhyQhJSr7zC2a3L7gOUDaAQ',
   'use': 'sig'}]}

import hashlib
## .. go to work here

Here's my attempt so far
The process as I understand is to use n & e to encode the header & payload, which should then match the signature.
# split the key into parts
s = jwt.split('.')
header = base64.b64decode(s[0] + '=' * (-len(s[0]) % 4))
payload = base64.b64decode(s[0] + '=' * (-len(s[0]) % 4))
sig = s[2]

# filter for correct jwk.
jwk = next((k for k in jwk['keys'] if k['kid']==json.loads(header)['kid']))

# Now I need to hash. In the RSA spec, it says SHA256
# is used for rs256
hashed_ph = hashlib.sha256(head_1+payload_2).hexdigest()

# now I need to pad the key, not sure to what length though.
# its 32 char by default.  The sig is 342 char length

# now the equation for varification, as far as i've found
# S^e = pad(hash(header+payload)) (mod n)
# S = signature
# e = e from the jwk
# hash is SHA256 according to rs256 spec
# n is n from the jwk
# pad is unknown.  

# I do not think (mod n) in the code means mathmaticall (mod n) means # pad(hash(header+payload)) % n
# I think it means:
pad_hex = lambda x, ct : (ct - len(x)) * '0' + x
padded_hashed_ph = pad_hex(hashed_ph, len(jwk['n']))

# All that should be left is:
# S^e = padded_hashed_ph


I'm stalled here, as above has two issues.

The output of padded_hashed_ph seems nonsensical, and in no way will equal the output of some_large_number**large_exponent
sig ** e takes forever to calculate.  I restarted the interpreter after 10 min.


The libraries (most of them) protect you from known attacks on JWTs, use them or proof your implementation is flawless.

If you want to verify a token signed with RS256 only with hashlib, you will have to implement RSA yourself. Note that in practice RSA is not just textbook RSA (i.e. simply an exponentiation), but also uses a (more or less complex) padding. In the case of RS256, this is RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, which is described in RFC8017. This requires a relatively high effort (and is not advisable with regard to e.g. side-channel attacks).

I did once create a websecurity library because I could not verify that the ones in JBoss & Glassfish were secure (we found out that you could imply leave out the signature in both of those libs, so they were actually broken). However, that's not for the weak of heart and I would advise against it if you haven't had much experience in handling cryptography. I was in a highly qualified R&D team specializing on implementing cryptography at that time.

There is never a place in RSA where you are computing something like sig ** e. You are always computing something like sig ** e mod n. And you don't do that by first computing sig ** e, and then taking that result mod n. Instead, you integrate the mod n part into the exponentiation part, an operation called modular exponentation. Python makes this trivial by providing a 3-argument form of pow, so that sig ** e mod n becomes simply pow(sig, e, n). The result of your exercise should be that you go back to something like pyJWT with better understanding.
